# Connecting printer via ipad 3 programmatically

Tags: ios

Hi all i just want to **print a pdf** which is displayed in my **UIWebView** through a **near by located printer in my ipad 3** can any one please provide me some samples ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Printing from the ipad is not very difficult, this tutorial: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/67176-airprint-tutorial-simple-print-file-30-lines-code.html shows you how to print anything from the ipad but you should be able to modify it to work for you. What I would do is take a programatic screenshot of the UIWebView and then print that image just like the tutorial does. Hope this helps!